# redirected page is not being displayed with spring-mvc ajax request

Tags: java, ajax, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

In my Spring MVC application, I want to redirect my page from `index.jsp` page to `final.jsp` page using AJAX. But the redirected page (final.jsp) is not being displayed when I click the `Redirect Page` button in my application. I have used `System.out.println("inside /redirect");` and `System.out.println("inside /finalPage");` inside my Java code to check whether the AJAX GET request is being received at server or not, and only `inside /redirect` is being printed which which means that the `/finalPage` is not being called. Moreover, my browser's console does not show any error. So please tell, what can be the problem and where is that problem? I have posted my complete code below:

**WebController.java**

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class WebController {

   @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String index() {
       return "index";
   }

   @RequestMapping(value = "/redirect", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String redirect() {
      System.out.println("inside /redirect");
      return "redirect:/finalPage";
   }

   @RequestMapping(value = "/finalPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String finalPage() {
       System.out.println("inside /finalPage");
      return "final";
   }
}
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@taglib uri = "http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix = "form"%>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Spring Page Redirection</title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h2>Spring Page Redirection</h2>
      <p>Click below button to redirect the result to new page</p>
      <button onClick="redFun()">Redirect Page</button>
      <script>
            function redFun() {
                $.ajax({
                    type : "GET",
                    url : "/HelloWeb/redirect"
                });
            }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

**final.jsp**

```
<%@taglib uri = "http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix = "form"%>
<html>

   <head>
      <title>Spring Page Redirection</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <h2>Redirected Page</h2>
   </body>

</html>
```

**web.xml:**

```
<web-app id = "WebApp_ID" version = "2.4"
   xmlns = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

   <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**HelloWeb-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package = "com.tutorialspoint" />

   <bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name = "prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your browser is not following the redirect because you're using ajax to hit your controller's redirect method. You have two options:

1. Don't use ajax at all, and let your browser respond naturally to the redirect status.

   ```
   function redFun() {
       window.location = "/HelloWeb/redirect";
   }
   ```
2. Look for an HTTP 302 response to the XmlHttpRequest, and change window.location to the value of the Location header in the response:

   ```
   function redFun() {
       $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "/HelloWeb/redirect"
       }).fail(function (jqXHR, status, err) {
           if (jqXHR.status === 302) {
               window.location = jqXHR.getResponseHeader('Location');
           }    
       });
   }
   ```